# WebGrid Ajax update, when webgrid_partial call from jQuery have no access to other pages

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

When `webgrid_partial` call as follow see no problem in result and can change pages (Ajax):

```
<div id="AjaxGridContent">
     @{
         @Html.Partial("_PartialUserWebGrid", Model.IEUser)
     }
</div>
```

But when call updated `webgrid_partial` from jQuery, only see first page with other pages link however when select other page link `<div>` tag to empty (blank)! And have no result and no access to webgrid!

My jQuery function:

```
function callpartial() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Home/SearchInfo",
        data: JSON.stringify({ txtFirstName: "", txtLastName: "" }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#imgLoading").hide();
            $('#AjaxGridContent').html(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("error")
        }
    });
    return;
};
```

my webgrid setting:

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(
        source: Model,
        defaultSort: "Id",
        rowsPerPage: 5,
        canPage: true,
        canSort: true,
        selectionFieldName: "SelectedRow",
        ajaxUpdateContainerId: "usergrid"
        );
}
@grid.GetHtml(
            htmlAttributes: new { id = "usergrid" },...other col prop.
```

"SearchInfo" Action:

```
public PartialViewResult SearchInfo(string txtLastName)
    {
        var model = BlUser.Select().Where(p => p.LastName.Contains(txtLastName)).ToList();
        return PartialView("_PartialUserWebGrid", model);
    }
```

How can i solve this problem?!

Comment: Pls post the code of the action 'SearchInfo'

Comment: Thanks for your attention, "SearchInfo" Action Code is Added.